# Why do object arrays in my ArrayList fail to retain their values?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am creating a program in Java to simulate evolution. The way I have it set up, each generation is composed of an array of Organism objects. Each of these arrays is an element in the ArrayList orgGenerations. Each generation, of which there could be any amount before all animals die, can have any amount of Organism objects.

For some reason, in my main loop when the generations are going by, I can have this code without errors, where allOrgs is the Organism array of the current generation and generationNumber is the number generations since the first.

```
orgGenerations.add(allOrgs);
printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(generationNumber));
```

printOrgs is a method to display an Organism array, where speed and strength are Organism Field variables:

```
public void printOrgs(Organism[] list)
{
    for (int x=0; x<list.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.println ("For organism number: " + x + ", speed is: " + list[x].speed + ", and strength is " + list[x].strength + ".");
    }
}
```

Later on, after this loop, when I am trying to retrieve the data to display, I call this very similar code:

```
printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(0));
```

This, and every other array in orgGenerations, return a null pointer exception on the print line of the for loop. Why are the Organism objects loosing their values?

Alright, here is all of the code from my main Simulation class. I admit, it might be sort of a mess. The parts that matter are the start and simulator methods. The battle ones are not really applicable to this problem. I think.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Simulator {

//variables for general keeping track
static Organism[] allOrgs;
static ArrayList<Organism[]> orgGenerations = new ArrayList <Organism[]>();

ArrayList<Integer> battleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int deathCount;
boolean done;
boolean runOnce;




//setup
Simulator()
{


    done = false;
    Scanner asker = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input number of organisms for the simulation: ");
    int numOfOrgs = asker.nextInt();
    asker.close();
    Organism[] orgArray = new Organism[numOfOrgs];

    for (int i=0; i<numOfOrgs; i++)
    {
        orgArray[i] = new Organism();
    }

    allOrgs = orgArray;
}

//graphsOrgs
public void graphOrgs() throws InterruptedException
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Evolution");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(1000,500);
    f.setVisible(true);

    Drawer bars = new Drawer();

    //System.out.println(orgGenerations.size());


    for (int iterator=0;iterator<(orgGenerations.size()-1); iterator++)
    {
        printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(0));
//The 0 can be any number, no matter what I do it wont work
        //System.out.println("first");
        f.repaint();

        bars.data = orgGenerations.get(iterator);

        f.add(bars);
        //System.out.println("before");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println("end");

    }

}

//prints all Orgs and their statistics
public void printOrgs(Organism[] list)
{
    System.out.println("Number Of Organisms: " + list.length);
    for (int x=0; x<list.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.println ("For organism number: " + x + ", speed is: " + list[x].speed + ", and strength is " + list[x].strength + ".");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//general loop for the organisms lives
public void start(int reproductionTime) throws InterruptedException
{

    int generationNumber = 0;

    orgGenerations.add(allOrgs);    
    printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(0));

    generationNumber++;


    while(true)
    {
        deathCount = 0;


        for(int j=0; j<reproductionTime; j++)
        {
            battleList.clear();

            for(int m=0; m<allOrgs.length; m++)
            {

                if (allOrgs[m].alive == true)
                    oneYearBattleCheck(m);  
            }

            battle();

        }

        reproduction();
        if (done == true)
            break;

        orgGenerations.add(allOrgs);
        printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(generationNumber));
        generationNumber++;
    }


    printOrgs(orgGenerations.get(2));
}


//Checks if they have to fight this year
private void oneYearBattleCheck(int m)
{
    Random chaos = new Random();
    int speedMod = chaos.nextInt(((int)Math.ceil(allOrgs[m].speed/5.0))+1);
    int speedSign = chaos.nextInt(2);

    if (speedSign == 0)
        speedSign--;

    speedMod *= speedSign;
    int speed = speedMod + allOrgs[m].speed;

    if (speed <= 0)
        speed=1;

    Random encounter = new Random();
    boolean battle = false;

    int try1 =(encounter.nextInt(speed));
    int try2 =(encounter.nextInt(speed));
    int try3 =(encounter.nextInt(speed));
    int try4 =(encounter.nextInt(speed));

    if (try1 == 0 || try2 == 0 || try3 == 0 || try4 == 0 )
    {
        battle = true;
    }


    if(battle == true)
    {
        battleList.add(m);
    }


}

//Creates the matches and runs the battle
private void battle()
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    if (battleList.size()%2 == 1)
    {

        int luckyDuck = rand.nextInt(battleList.size());
        battleList.remove(luckyDuck);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<(battleList.size()-1);)
    {
        int competitor1 = rand.nextInt(battleList.size());
        battleList.remove(competitor1);
        int competitor2 = rand.nextInt(battleList.size());
        battleList.remove(competitor2);

        //Competitor 1 strength
        int strengthMod = rand.nextInt(((int)Math.ceil(allOrgs[competitor1].strength/5.0))+1);
        int strengthSign = rand.nextInt(2);

        if (strengthSign == 0)
            strengthSign--;

        strengthMod *= strengthSign;
        int comp1Strength = strengthMod + allOrgs[competitor1].strength;


        //Competitor 2 strength
        strengthMod = rand.nextInt(((int)Math.ceil(allOrgs[competitor2].strength/5.0))+1);
        strengthSign = rand.nextInt(2);

        if (strengthSign == 0)
            strengthSign--;

        strengthMod *= strengthSign;
        int comp2Strength = strengthMod + allOrgs[competitor2].strength;


        //Fight!
        if (comp1Strength>comp2Strength)
        {
            allOrgs[competitor1].life ++;
            allOrgs[competitor2].life --;
        }
        else if (comp2Strength>comp1Strength)
        {
            allOrgs[competitor2].life ++;
            allOrgs[competitor1].life --;
        }


        if (allOrgs[competitor1].life == 0)
        {
            allOrgs[competitor1].alive = false;
            deathCount++;
        }
        if (allOrgs[competitor2].life == 0)
        {
            allOrgs[competitor2].alive = false;
            deathCount ++ ;
        }
    }

}

//New organisms
private void reproduction()
{

    //System.out.println("Number of deaths: " + deathCount + "\n");
    if (deathCount>=(allOrgs.length-2))
    {
        done = true;
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<Organism> tempOrgs = new ArrayList<Organism>();
    Random chooser = new Random();
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        int partner1 = 0;
        int partner2 = 0;
        boolean partnerIsAlive = false;
        boolean unluckyDuck = false;

        //choose partner1
        while (partnerIsAlive == false)
        {
            partner1 = chooser.nextInt(allOrgs.length);
            if (allOrgs[partner1] != null)
            {
                if (allOrgs[partner1].alive == true)
                {
                    partnerIsAlive = true;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
        //System.out.println("Count 2: " + count);

        partnerIsAlive = false;

        //choose partner2
        while (partnerIsAlive == false)
        {
            if (count+deathCount == (allOrgs.length))
            {
                unluckyDuck=true;
                break;
            }

            partner2 = chooser.nextInt(allOrgs.length);

            if (allOrgs[partner2] != null)
            {
                if (allOrgs[partner2].alive == true)
                {
                    partnerIsAlive = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (unluckyDuck == false)
            count++;

        //System.out.println("count 2: " + count);

        if (unluckyDuck == false)
        {
            int numOfChildren = (chooser.nextInt(4)+1);
            for (int d=0; d<numOfChildren; d++)
            {
                tempOrgs.add(new Organism(allOrgs[partner1].speed, allOrgs[partner2].speed, allOrgs[partner1].strength, allOrgs[partner2].strength ));
            }

            allOrgs[partner1] = null;
            allOrgs[partner2] = null;
        }


        if (count+deathCount == (allOrgs.length))
        {
            Arrays.fill(allOrgs, null);
            allOrgs = tempOrgs.toArray(new Organism[tempOrgs.size()-1]);
            break;
        }
        //System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

}

Main method:

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    Simulator sim = new Simulator();
    int lifeSpan = 20;
    sim.start(lifeSpan);
    sim.graphOrgs();

}
```

}

Organism class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Organism {
static Random traitGenerator = new Random();

int life;
int speed;
int strength;
boolean alive;



Organism()
{
    speed = (traitGenerator.nextInt(49)+1);
    strength = (50-speed);
    life = 5;
    alive = true;
}

Organism(int strength1, int strength2, int speed1, int speed2)
{
    Random gen = new Random();
    int speedMod = gen.nextInt(((int)Math.ceil((speed1+speed2)/10.0))+1);
    int speedSign = gen.nextInt(2);


    if (speedSign == 0)
        speedSign--;
    speedMod *= speedSign;
    //System.out.println(speedMod);

    int strengthMod = gen.nextInt(((int)Math.ceil((strength1+strength2)/10.0))+1);
    int strengthSign = gen.nextInt(2);

    if (strengthSign == 0)
        strengthSign--;
    strengthMod *= strengthSign;
    //System.out.println(strengthMod);

    strength = (((int)((strength1+strength2)/2.0))+ strengthMod);
    speed = (((int)((speed1+speed2)/2.0))+ speedMod);
    alive = true;
    life = 5;
}


}
```

The problem lies in the graphOrgs class when I try to print to check if it is working in preparation for graphing the results. This is when it returns the error. When I try placing the print code in other places in the Simulator class the same thing occurs, a null pointer error. This happens even if it is just after the for loop where the element has been established.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any null elements in `orgGenerations`? By default, an array's cell is `null`, explaining why `list[x]` might throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You should include more code, since we have no idea what `orgGenerations.get(generationNumber)` contains.

Comment: I mean, I am calling the same elements that I already defined. Unless they got null somewhere between, which I don't think occurred.

Comment: You mean you *think* you are calling the same elements. Post your code, which will either prove or disprove that assertion.

Comment: You need to post more code so we can reproduce, we have no idea how the datas are "added" which make it impossible to explain the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Alright I posted everything relevant. Hope its not too overwhelming, but you did ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code that sets to null elements in your `allOrgs` array.

```
        allOrgs[partner1] = null;
        allOrgs[partner2] = null;
```

Your `orgGenerations` list contains the same `allOrgs` instance multiple times.

Therefore, when you write `allOrgs[partner1] = null`, the `partner1`'th element becomes null in all the list elements of `orgGenerations`, which is why the print method fails.

You should create a copy of the array (you can use `Arrays.copy`) each time you add a new generation to the list (and consider also creating copies of the `Organism` instances, if you want each generation to record the past state of the `Organism`s and not their final state).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and I see where I made those mistakes. Thanks!